# Colon in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, guile

```
(show-data 'YHOO :config 'my-config)
```

I saw some Scheme code (in Guile) like the line above and get confused with the **colon** syntax `:config` .

What kind of language features of this? Is it a intrinsic feature of Scheme, or specially designed for the Guile lib? How does it work? I kept searching this online but still found nothing. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a keyword and its purpose is to make the invocation of a procedure that receives optional arguments easier and convenient.

You can read more about this feature in this [section](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Keywords.html) of the Guile Reference Manual.

Comment: Thanks! That's it! I noticed that (read-set! keywords 'prefix) should be added before using keywords without the # symbol.